# create a nested JSON object with PHP

Tags: php, json

What is the correct way to define this kind of JSON object in PHP

```
{
"label": "Europe (EU27)",
"data": [[1999, 3.0], [2000, 3.9], [2001, 2.0], [2002, 1.2], [2003, 1.3], [2004, 2.5], [2005, 2.0], [2006, 3.1], [2007, 2.9], [2008, 0.9]]
}
```

I need to create a nested array that will be converted to JSON object via `json_encode()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create php arrays however you need to and json encode it. It's the same structure: **[Live demo (click).](http://codepad.viper-7.com/qt7dBd)**

```
$myArr = [
  "label" => "Europe (EU27)",
  "data"=> [[1999, 3.0], [2000, 3.9], [2001, 2.0], [2002, 1.2], [2003, 1.3], [2004, 2.5], [2005, 2.0], [2006, 3.1], [2007, 2.9], [2008, 0.9]]
];

$json = json_encode($myArr);
```

Just note that the nice array syntax `[]` isn't supported before PHP 5.4, so you have to use `array()` instead if you're on and older version.

Comment: unfortunately I need to use array(), can you please provide me with the right code. Thank you.

Comment: @user2703038 you simply write `array()` instead of `[]`.

Comment: @user2703038 Please be aware, this is StackOverflow, not CopyPasteOverflow. Do a bit of the leg-work yourself.

Comment: @DanLugg Oh, I'm terribly sorry, I actually thought that this is place for posting witty comments to satisfy my own ego instead of helping others. Please forgive me.

Comment: @m59 There is no excuse for that, I'm aware, but It was out of my negligence, it was not intentional. However, that comment was planned and there for a reason. I expressed my appreciation by thanking the people who provided the answer.

Comment: @user2703038 no problem :) I know Dan Lugg and he's helped me quite a bit. He didn't mean any more than to just point out that a simple google and a little work would have answered your question. It's not worth being offended.

Comment: @m59 I'm sorry, I know I sounded a bit cynical. I helped people all my life and never asked anything in return. Some people even took advantage of that. I wish i could buy you a beer or something instead of just clicking the checkmark. I truly appreciate all the help.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$json = new stdClass;

$json->label = "Europe (EU27)";
$json->data= [
    [1999, 3.0],
    [2000, 3.9],
    [2001, 2.0],
    [2002, 1.2],
    [2003, 1.3],
    [2004, 2.5],
    [2005, 2.0],
    [2006, 3.1],
    [2007, 2.9],
    [2008, 0.9]
];
```

If you'll call `json_encode` on `$json` you'll get exactly what you want.

Comment: That's awkward to me. You can't create the structure directly (all at once). You have to keep adding first level items. It makes more sense to me just to use an array.

Comment: In most cases you wont be able to create stucture all at once, because of its' complexity :)